# For Loops, and Reading Strings from a Text File, Not Working

Tags: php

It's hard for me to explicitly state my exact issue, but I'll try to explain the best I can.

(Sorry for the long post)

I have lines in a file called singles.txt that look like this.

```
Ada Lovelace,F,96,ISTJ,Linux,24,99
Adele Goldberg,F,65,ENFJ,Windows,50,70
Alan Turing,M,41,ESTP,Mac OS X,31,50
```

In this scenario I have a user, whos name, etc. is in this file aswell as many others. I first loop over the file to find the user's info inside the file so that I can then reference their info via variables. After this I loop over the file again, to start comparing the user's info to others found in the file. I have an if statement inside this for loop that repeats a certain div for everytime the condition is for the if statement is met. For some reason when I load the page it doesn't repeat the div at all. Hopefully my code can explain my problem more than I can.

```
$name = $_GET["name"];

<?php>
$singles = file('singles.txt');

for($i = 0; $i < count($singles); $i++){
$searchsingle = explode(',', $singles[$i]);

if($searchsingle[0] == $name){
    $yougender = $searchsingle[1];
    $youage = $searchsingle[2];
    $youperson = $searchsingle[3];
    $youOS = $searchsingle[4];
    $youmin = $searchsingle[5];
    $youmax = $searchsingle[6];
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($singles); $i++){
$searchsingle = explode(',', $singles[$i]);

if($yougender !== $searchsingles[1] 
&& $youOS == $searchsingle[4] 
&& $youmin >= $searchsingle[2] 
&& $youmax <= $searchsingle[2]){  
    $theirname = $searchsingle[0];
    $theirage = $searchsingle[2];
    $theirgender = $searchsingle[1];
    $theirOS = $searchsingle[4];
    $theirperson = $searchsingle[3];
?>
```

The div to be repeated. (occurs right after the previous code)

```
<div class="match">
<p> <img src="user" alt="Single"> <?php echo $theirname ?> </p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Gender: <?php echo $theirgender ?> </strong></li> </br>
<li><strong>Age: <?php echo $theirage ?> </strong></li> </br>
<li><strong>Type: <?php echo $theirperson ?> </strong></li> </br>
<li><strong>OS: <?php echo $theirOS ?> </strong></li> </br>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

</body>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$yougender !== $searchsingle[1] 
&& $youOS == $searchsingle[4] 
&& $youmin >= $searchsingle[2] 
&& $youmax <= $searchsingle[2]` -- which means, this condition evaluates to `FALSE` every time. Find out why.

Comment: Thank you for giving me somewhere to look, i've been really lost :).

Comment: Hey, I figured it out! :) Thanks again

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)